# Двумерный vector

Tags: массивы, c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать, заполнить и вывести двумерный `vector`. С одномерным все ясно, а вот двумерные никак не могу понять((

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь,вроде разобрался))

Comment: Всем ответившим - по пирожку.

Comment: @mikillskegg, @arlek, а лучше выбрать наилучший ответ и закрыть тему ;)

Comment: Ну, это уже не ко мне.

Comment: Если объявляю в классе: DynamicArray<int> ids; DynamicArray<AnsiString> names; vector < vector <int> > a(1, vector <int> (1) ); int WinAct;
То выдает ошибку: E2303 Type name expected

Comment: Если подключаю к файлу .h; соответсвующий файл .cpp - ошибка пропадает    #include "WinTables.h"
#include "WinTables.cpp"

Answer (score 15):

Если известны размеры (или один):

```
vector<vector<T> > a(n, vector<T>(m, значение)); // два размера
vector<vector<T> > b(n, vector<T>()); // один размер
```

Можно указать значение, которым нужно заполнить вектор. Если `T` — класс, и значение не указано, то будет использован конструктор по умолчанию.

Например:

```
vector<int> c(n, -1); // вектор, заполненный -1 
vector<my_class> d(m, my_class("Hello, World!", 42));
```

Если число элементов заранее не известно, то можно воспользоваться `push_back()`:

```
vector<vector<T> > e;
e.push_back(vector<T>());
```

Answer (score 9):

```
#include <iostream>   // Так надо
#include <vector>     // Для вектора
using namespace std;  // Чтобы не мучатся

int main()
{
    int n, m;       // Создание переменных отвечающих за размер вектора
    cin >> n >> m;  // Ввод размеров вектора

    vector < vector <int> > a(n, vector <int> (m) ); // Объявление вектора на n строк по m элементов 

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)     // Цикл, который идёт по строкам
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) // Цикл, который идёт по элементам
        {
            cin >> a[i][j]; // Заполнение вектора или массива (в данном случае ввод)
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // Цикл, который идёт по строкам
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) // Цикл, который идёт по элементам
            cout << a[i][j] << ' '; // Вывод элементов i строки вектора
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ваш код будет работать верно только для квадратных матриц.

Comment: @vp_arth вероятно, опечатка. Заменить `n` на `m` во вторых циклах

Answer (score 5):

```
vector< vector <int> > vvi;
//... initial
for(vector<vector<int> >::iterator it = vvi.begin(); it != vvi.end(); ++it){
    for(vector<int>::iterator it2 = (*it).begin(); it2 != (*it).end(); ++it2){
        // ...out
    }
}
```

Как то так

Answer (score 5):

```
vector< vector<int> > v;
v.push_back( vector<int>() );
v[v.size()-1].push_back(100500);
int a=v[i][j];
```

не компилировал... но по памяти вроде так.

Answer (score 3):

Если массив будет прямоугольным и его размеры будет неизменными, то можно сделать класс, который одномерный массив разворачивает в линейный:

```
template<typename T> class Array2D
{
public:
    Array2D(size_t w, size_t h): width(w), height(h), data(new T[w*h]) {}
    ~Array2D() {delete[] data;}
    T* operator[](size_t i) {return data+i*height;}
    const T* operator[](size_t i) const {return data+i*height;}
private:
    T* data;
    size_t width, height;
}
```

Или, используя std::vector внутри:

```
template<typename T> class Array2D
{
public:
    Array2D(size_t w, size_t h): width(w), data(w*h) {}
    T* operator[](size_t i) {return data.data()+i*height;}
    const T* operator[](size_t i) const {return data.data()+i*height;}
private:
    std::vector<T> data;
    size_t width;
    //height не храним, так как при желании его можно посчитать, поделив data.size() на width
}
```

Он ведёт себя так же, как и обычные двумерные массивы, но его размеры определяются во время выполнения программы, а не во время компиляции, как у обычных статических массивов.
 Строка кода

```
Array2D<int> array(10, 20);
```

аналогична такому объявлению статического массива

```
int array[10][20];
```

Заполняются они так же, допустим, так:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<20; j++)
        array[i][j]=i+j;
```

Преимущество этого класса в том, что мы выделяем память одним непрерывным блоком, как и статический массив в Си. Кроме того, в operator[] можно добавить проверки выхода за пределы массива. Но выход за пределы строки проверить нельзя, не усложняя класс прокси-объектами. Такой выход за пределы строки даст нам элемент следующей строки.

Comment: Все правильно, только чел спрашивал именно про vector из STL.

Comment: Он спросил "как написать, заполнить и вывести двумерный vector.". Неизвестно, он имел в виду именно std::vector или какой-то похожий велосипед. В любом случае, про vector<vector<int>> ему уже ответили, поэтому я думаю, это не помешает.

Comment: Спасибо всем! Мне вся информацию пригодится!)

Answer (score 2):

Правильный ответ (массив n - строк, m - столбцов)

```
vector< vector<int> > matrix(n, vector<int> (m, 0));
```

Comment: А кто вам сказал что он правильный? :)

Answer (score 1):

Инициализация (значения подобрал для примера):

```
std::vector <std::vector <int>> A = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
```

Вывод:

```
for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < A[i].size(); j++)
    {
        std::cout << A[i][j];
    }
}
```