# Объявление двумерного вектора в шапке .h

Tags: c++, qt, vector

когда перемещаю в .h файл объявление вектора двумерного:

```
...
class PollutionZone : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit PollutionZone(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~PollutionZone();
    const int X_MAX = 500; // Размеры накладываемой сетки
    const int Y_MAX = 500;       
    std::vector <std::vector<bool>> MapWaterside(Y_MAX,  std::vector <bool>(X_MAX));
    ...
};
```

Появляется ошибка:C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
Ругается на Y_MAX.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan можно пожалуйста переписать, как должно быть.

Comment: все уже написал Ant. Я  сказал не так как хотел, удалил. Читайте ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ругается на самом деле на

```
std::vector <std::vector<bool>> MapWaterside(Y_MAX,  std::vector <bool>(X_MAX));
```

Во-первых, в определении класса не допускается непосредственное применение `()`-инициализаторов к членам класса. Допустимы только `{}` или `=` инициализаторы. В вашем случае можно поступить так

```
std::vector<std::vector<bool>> MapWaterside = std::vector(Y_MAX,  std::vector <bool>(X_MAX));
```

или так

```
const std::size_t X_MAX = 500;
const std::size_t Y_MAX = 500;       
std::vector <std::vector<bool>> MapWaterside = { Y_MAX, std::vector <bool>(X_MAX) };
```

(Обратите внимание, что тип `int` напрямую неприменим внутри `{}`-инициализатора для задания размера вектора, ибо получается сужающее преобразование.)

Во-вторых, не забывайте, что инициализатор для *нестатического* члена класса - это лишь "заготовка", которая физически будет использована только позже - в коде конструктора класса. Причем там у вас будет возможность "перекрыть" инициализаторы, указанные в определении класса. Это относится и к `MapWaterside`, и к `X_MAX` и `Y_MAX` тоже. Порядок инициализации, как всегда, соответствует порядку объявления. То есть если вы напишете в конструкторе

```
PollutionZone::PollutionZone(QWidget *parent) : Y_MAX(1000)
  {}
```

то `Y_MAX` получит значение `1000` и вектор будет проинициализирован для `Y_MAX = 1000`. Вы хотели достичь такого эффекта? Вам нужна такая возможность? Если нет, то возможно вам лучше подойдут

```
static constexpr int X_MAX = 500; // или `unsigned`, или `std::size_t`
static constexpr int Y_MAX = 500;
```

Comment: а как правильно можно переписать объявление двумерного вектора в .h ?

Comment: тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/57957/%D0%94%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-vector нашёл такое объявление: vector<vector<T> > a(n, vector<T>(m, значение)); // два размера

Comment: @Ivan Triumphov: Это прекрасно, но в вашем случае речь идет именно об инициализаторе сделанном **внутри определения класса**. Это совсем другая история - новая фича для С++11 со своими особенными свойствами. Ваше пример по ссылке тут напрямую не применим.

Comment: Да спасибо за ответ разобрался)))

Comment: а как обращаться к значению вектора?    for (int i=1;i<=Y_MAX;i++) {
        for (int j=1;j<=X_MAX;j++) {
           
        } 
    }

Comment: вроде так :    for (std::size_t i=1;i<=Y_MAX;i++) {
        for (std::size_t j=1;j<=X_MAX;j++) {
           MapWaterside[i][j]=0; 
        } 
    }