# Требуется спецификатор типа: вложенные классы. C++

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

При попытке инициализации члена класса, являющегося при этом объектом вложенного класса, возникает ошибка. Вот код:

```
class rage 
{
public:
    rage() { }

private:
    class test
    {
    public:
        test(int y) { }
    };
    test heythere(5);  // <-- Ошибка тут
};

int main()
{
}
```

Visual Studio кричит об ошибке в строчке `test heythere(5);`, подчеркивает `5` и говорит, что требуется спецификатор типа, но это мало мне о чём говорит.

Comment: При чем если бы это был невложенный класс,то конструктор работает нормально..

Comment: Фактически дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/928530/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5-h/928532#928532 Только тот вопрос перегружен деталями, продраться через которые новичку будет трудно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> test heythere(5);
> ```
>
> main.cpp:31:19: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
> main.cpp:31:19: error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant

Если вы инициализируете поле прямо в теле класса, нужно использовать либо `= …`, либо `{…}`.

`(…)` - нельзя. Видимо потому, что в таком случае для компилятора становится слишком сложно отличить объявление поля с инициализатором от объявления метода (где скобки были бы списком параметров).

На это намекает даже название такого инициализатора в грамматике языка: *brace-or-equal-initializer*.

Подойдет один из следующих вариантов, на выбор:

```
test heythere = 5;
test heythere = test(5);
test heythere{5};
test heythere = {5};
test heythere = test{5};
```

Конкретно в этом случае все пять ведут себя совершенно одинаково, но в общем случае между ними есть разница. Подробнее тут: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization

Еще вариант: Оставить только `test heythere;`, а инициализацию выполнять в списке инициализации в конструкторе: `rage() : heythere(5) {...}`. (Либо `: heythere{5}`.)

Comment: Спасибо,помог) Сам бы я точно не разобрался,ибо это особый случай,как я понимаю

Comment: это не особый случай, а очень даже обычный(нормальный).