# c++ ООП двумерные массивы

Tags: c++, ооп, sfml

я начал писать свою игру на `c++ sfml`, но в самом начале столкнулся с одной **ОЧЕНЬ** не понятной проблемой(

суть проблемы, что мне надо в одном классе создать двумерный массив, а в остальных получать их, да да да знаю это очень глупый вопрос, но я вообще ничего не понимаю!

вот какая структура проекта:

```
   Program.cpp
   Settings.hpp
   lib/
      Tile.hpp
      Chunk.hpp
      World.hpp
      Game.hpp
      Content.hpp
    image/
      Lerraria_Tile.png
```

Компилирую вот так:

```
g++ Program.cpp -o Lerraria -pthread -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lsfml-audio -lsfml-graphics
```

ОС `Lunux Ubuntu`

Program.cpp:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#include "Settings.hpp"

#include "lib/Tile.hpp"
#include "lib/Chunk.hpp"
#include "lib/World.hpp"
#include "lib/Content.hpp"

using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(Window_Width,Window_Height),Window_Title);
    Event ev;
    Content::load();

    Chunk chunk;

    while(window.isOpen())
    {
        while(window.pollEvent(ev)) if(ev.type==Event::Closed) window.close(); //close window

        window.clear(Color::Cyan);

        window.draw(chunk);

        window.display();
    }

}
```

lib/Content.hpp:

```
/*
*   load texture in this file
*/

#ifndef Content_T
#define Content_T

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "../Settings.hpp"


Texture texture_blocks;
Sprite sprite_block_GROUND;

class Content
{
public:

    static void load()
    {
        texture_blocks.setSmooth(true);
        texture_blocks.loadFromFile("image/Lerraria_Tile.png");

        sprite_block_GROUND.setTexture(texture_blocks);
        sprite_block_GROUND.setTextureRect(IntRect(1,1,24,24));
    }

};



#endif //Content_T
```

Settings.hpp:

```
/*
*   Settings file
*/
#ifndef Settings_T
#define Settings_T

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
using namespace sf;

int Window_Width = 800;
int Window_Height = 400;
String Window_Title = "Lerraria";

int GroundLVL = 10;

#endif
```

lib/Tile.hpp:

```
/*
*   this file is class tile's
*/
#ifndef Tile_T
#define Tile_T

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include "../Settings.hpp"
#include "Content.hpp"

using namespace sf;


class Tile : public Drawable, public Transformable
{
public:

    enum texture_state   //all states tile
    {
        NONE,
        GROUND,
        GRASS
    };

    Tile(float X, float Y)
    {
        typeTile = GROUND; //default
    }

    virtual void draw(RenderTarget& target, RenderStates states) const
    {
        states.transform*=getTransform();
        target.draw(sprite_block_GROUND, states);
    }

protected:

    float Tile_CoordX;
    float Tile_CoordY;
    int typeTile;

};

#endif
```

lib/Chunk.hpp:

```
/*
*   this file is class chunk's
*/

#ifndef Chunk_T
#define Chunk_T

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>

#include "../Settings.hpp"
#include "Tile.hpp"

using namespace sf;


const short int CHUNK_SIZE = 16;

class Chunk : public Drawable, public Transformable
{
public:

    Chunk()
    {
        IT_tile[0][0] = Tile(0,0);
    }

    virtual void draw(RenderTarget& target, RenderStates states) const
    {
        states.transform*=getTransform();
        target.draw(IT_tile[0][0], states);
    }

protected:

    std::deque<std::deque<Tile>> tiles;             //в данном коде я использовал ДЭК, но можно показать как это делается и в двумерными массивами
    std::deque<std::deque<Tile>>::iterator IT_tile;

};

#endif
```

World и Game сейчас не важны, покажите просто на примере чанков и тайлов.

Comment: P.S у меня вызывается ошибка

Comment: 1) лучше что нить типо CMake заюзать. 2. Создать массив и юзать его везде ? почитайте про паттерн фабрика ))

Comment: Andrey, ну я все равно не понимаю, скинь код как создать массив в классе и юзать в другом УМОЛЯЮ

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) сначала надо это почитать

Comment: А вот ответ про двумерный вектор https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/57957/%D0%94%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-vector

Comment: СПАСИБО ТЕБЕ ДОБРЕЙШИЙ ЧЕЛОВЕК!!!!!! все работает